# How to get 10.8 SDK and 5.1 compiler in Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, xcode6, osx-mavericks, llvm-clang

as from the title, I need to use the 10.8 SDK and the 5.1 (or 5.0) LLVM compiler with Xcode 6, in Mavericks.
With the previous Xcode, it was possible to have both the SDKs, but now I see only the 10.9 one.
How can I install the previous SDK and  compiler in Xcode 6?

Comment: You can target 10.8 using the 10.9 SDK.

Comment: Of course you can; however, some of us want to target earlier versions, and we'd rather not risk occasional random bugs that turn up when you change the SDK until we've had time to test those...  I am also looking for an easy answer to this question

Answer (score 13):

It's probably not supported by Apple, but I've seen good results by copying the 10.8 SDK from the Xcode 5.1.1 DMG.

```
sudo cp -a /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk \
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried different ways, and it seems that both @trojanfoe and @byronc are right. On the one hand, by targeting 10.8 with the 10.9 SDK, all the compiling stuff ends fine, so it seems to me the most correct way, using "official" Apple stuff. On the other, when I tried to copy and paste the 10.8 SDK from an old Xcode 5 installation to the Xcode 6 correct folder, the SDK showed up in my project, so this way seems functional too, even if I think it is not the most clear way.